# Loop a function that returns a list over variables in a dataframe grouped by another variable

Tags: r, list, loops, asbio

As an example dataset

```
example.df <- data.frame( 
species = sample(c("primate", "non-primate"), 50, replace = TRUE),
treated = sample(c("Yes", "No"), 50, replace = TRUE), 
gender = sample(c("male", "female"), 50, replace = TRUE), 
var1 = rnorm(50, 100, 5), var2=rnorm(50, 10,5), var3 = rnorm (50, 25, 5))
```

I am trying to use `pairw.kw` from the `asbio` package to calculate dunn test P-values after grouping by a variable.

```
by(example.df,example.df$treated, function(X) pairw.kw(X$var1, X$species, conf = 0.95))
```

returns a valid result.

How can I modify this code (or some other way) to  loop over the other numeric variables (I have 23 in my actual dataset)?

Edit: I used the following code to solve my question based on the excellent answers from @jay.sf below.

```
vars <- colnames(select_if(example.df, is.numeric))
res <- by(example.df, example.df$treated, simplify = FALSE, function(X) sapply(vars, simplify = FALSE, USE.NAMES = TRUE, function(i) pairw.kw(X[[i]], X$species, conf = 0.95)))
res_summary <- res %>% map_depth(2, "summary")
res_summary.df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(sapply(res_summary, `[`, simplify = FALSE, USE.NAMES = TRUE), data.frame))
```

This converts the summary object that's the only thing I need from `res` and converts it into a dataframe that is easy to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just build in a `sapply()` that loops through the various variables. First, we need a character vector that contains the names of the numeric names.

```
(vars <- names(example.df)[4:6])
# [1] "var1" "var2" "var3"
```

Now we put that in the `by(.)`

```
library("asbio")
res <- by(example.df, example.df$treated, function(X) sapply(vars, function(i)
  pairw.kw(X[[i]], X$species, conf = 0.95)))
```

Finally you can run `str(res)` to see what is in the result and how to access it.

E.g.

```
> res$Yes[[4]]
                                        Diff    Lower   Upper Decision Adj. P-value
Avg.ranknon-primate-Avg.rankprimate -0.19444 -5.55705 5.16817   FTR H0     0.943345
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. `Error in split.default(X, group) : first argument must be a vector`  I get this error message when I run the code. Also, the actual variables I need to loop over all have different names and are not sequentially named var1, var 2 and so on.

Comment: The code is working fine for me with the example data you've given, though. I've edited the answer to make it easier for you to adapt it to your original data.

Comment: Thanks. I had other packages also loaded when I first ran the code. When I used a fresh R session with just `dplyr` and `asbio` along with base R loaded, I was able to run it without errors. I am not sure why this happens. I have marked this as the answer.

Comment: I used the following code, modifying the code you had posted.. `(vars <- colnames(select_if(example.df, is.numeric)))` and `res <- by(example.df, example.df$treated, simplify = FALSE, function(X) sapply(vars, simplify = FALSE, USE.NAMES = TRUE, function(i) pairw.kw(X[[i]], X$species, conf = 0.95)))` in order to preserve the names and list structure. How would I go about extracting the summary dataframes and binding each variable's results together from the "yes" and "no" groups? Thanks.